# Python: Circular Import error, eventhough no "from ... import ..." used

Tags: python, class, circular-dependency

I am struggeling with resolving a circular import issue. My setup is as follows:

Module `a.py`:

```py
import b

class A():
    pass
```

Module `b.py`:

```py
import a

class Bar(a.A):
    pass
```

Notice the circular import in module `b`: is needs to access class `A` from module `a`, because `B` inherits from `A`.

Finally, the main module, `main.py`:

```py
import a

# ...
```

When I run `main.py`, I get this error:

```
$ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a
  File "/home/.../a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import b
  File "/home/.../b.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Bar(a.A):
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'a' has no attribute 'A' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I thought, one way of resolving circular imports was to not use the `from ... import ...` statement, which I didn't do as you can see. But why am I still getting that error then?

**EDIT**: My current code structure requires that A and B are separate modules. Nevertheless, in this [video](https://youtu.be/UnKa_t-M_kM?t=141), he is using a similar structure as mine, and he has no problems...

Comment: A question to ask is: why does `a.py` need to import `b`? Can you avoid that?

Comment: @9769953 No, I can't avoid that, because `a.py` also accesses stuff from `b`

Comment: `a.py` **must not** `import b`. If `A` needs stuff from `B` then your class / code structure is wrong, maybe put `A` and `B` in the same file then.

Comment: Then make a third module `c` where you put the class definition of `Bar`.

Comment: But if a needs b, and b needs a, you might want to restructure your modules in the first place (one suggestion is in the comment above).

Comment: I found this video: https://youtu.be/UnKa_t-M_kM?t=156 There he is using similar structure as mine, and he doesn't get that error?

Comment: That situation is different, b/c he's not trying to subclass a class definition in `a`. Take the advice of the others above - **avoid circular imports**.

Comment: The video only *uses* the import in a function, which is not run at compile time. Your class definitions are run at compile time. Also note the third (easy) solution.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal answer in such cases is usually to

- combine the files or their contents (do you actually need more files?)
- create a 3rd file and put shared contents into it (avoids breaking existing imports as you can simply import whatever you need into the existing libraries from the shared one)
- create a 3rd file which imports both (cleaner with 3rd party libraries, but may break existing logic)

```py
import a
import b

class Bar(a.A):
    pass
```